# Can't send transactions on private test net

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have created a private test net according to the [tutorial](https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html). Then i've created 2 accounts and i've one of them a bit of ether.
Now i try to send some ether :

```
tx = eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: amount})
```

I try it several times and like u can see on the picture nothing happened.

How can i resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For succeeded those Transanctions the server should be mining in the same time. And it's take some time (5-7)mins to a succesful transactions.